# Printing DataGridView Without converting it to bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Most of the solutions I've found and I know for printing a datagridview are based on converting it to a bitmap image and then sending it for printing. Even MSDN is saying the same thing.

So how can I print the only the content ? Do I have to read each row one by one and save them in a string array or something like this ?

Edit:
@Robert 
The idea is good, but how exactly I can do this ?

Comment: [Try me](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32224/Exporting-a-DataGridView-to-Excel-in-NET-2-0-C-cod).

Comment: It didn't work for me, I came across that before

Comment: We will need to see some code to help then, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that I came up with for a similar project is to export the data to an Excel spreadsheet, giving the user the choice to save the file or print it later.  I'm not sure if you're want to go that route, however, but it's an option.

Comment: I though about the same thing but, I don't have any idea how it can be done .

Comment: That solution doesn't work, it causes an error, it say : Object reference not set to an instance of object

Comment: I've done it 2 different ways, but here is a short example of how I'm doing it in one of my projects.

Comment: Can you please send me the examples ?

Comment: I've done it 2 different ways, but here is a short example of how I'm doing it in one of my projects.  Include "using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;" at the top.  Let me write some lines of code in another comment....

Comment: Then in the function you're using, something like: Excel.ApplicationClass excel = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true);   After that, you can add text to the cells directly, for example:  excel.Cells[1, 1] = "some text"; excel.Cells[1, 2] = "other text";  Finally, when you want to push it out:  Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;
string SheetName = "somefilename.xlsx";
worksheet.SaveAs(Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"] + "temp\\" + SheetName);
excel.Quit();
Response.Redirect("~/temp/" + SheetName);

Comment: This method involves saving a temp file on the server.  There is another way to do it without involving the server, however.  I'm looking for examples of that way right now...

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using Response.Write to create an output file, like this:

```
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">");
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Reports.xls");
                //sets font
                Response.Write("<font style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri;'>");
                Response.Write("<br/><br/><br/>");
Response.Write("<table border='1' bgColor='#ffffff' borderColor='#000000' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' style='font-family:Calibri; background:white;'>");
    ...More output data ...            // Send to save
                Response.Write("</table>");
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
```

Comment: In between the table tags, add your data in a table format, with rows and columns.  This works faster than the 1st example and doesn't save any files on the server.